# Is it possible to import multiple node types in the same csv in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to import some different types of nodes in neo4j where the nodes only differ on the type and not the data. Is it possible to import something like this:

```
NodeType,Id,Name
NodeX,1,Yolo
NodeY,2,World
```

And get two nodes, one of type `NodeX` and one of type `NodeY` somehow?

What I would like to write is something like this:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///nodes.csv" as row
WITH row WHERE row.Id IS NOT NULL
MERGE (c:row.NodeType {id: row.Id, name: row.Name});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the APOC procedure [apoc.merge.node](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/graph-updates/data-creation/) to do the equivalent of `MERGE` for nodes with dynamically-assigned labels:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///nodes.csv" as row
WITH row WHERE row.Id IS NOT NULL
CALL apoc.merge.node([row.NodeType], {id: row.Id, name: row.Name}) YIELD node
RETURN node
```

Comment: Cool, will test it out. Thanks! As a workaround I started generating one line of CREATE per thing I wanted to do, but that isn't so performant.

Comment: Right, and that also exposes you to "Cypher injection" attacks via the file data.